# How to combine rows of a dataframe in R based on values from two different rows?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

`> humcon
  seqnames    start      end    TAS Proxy.start Proxy.end Assembly_NCBI
1        6 28179560 28239932 rs1635  rs78270345 rs4711167     GRCh38.p7
2        6 28239933 28294888 rs1635  rs78270345 rs4711167     GRCh38.p7
3        3 52833805 52847601 rs3617      rs3617 rs2071044     GRCh38.p7
4       15 91426560 91426560 rs4702      rs4702    rs4702     GRCh38.p7
5       19 45382034 45382034 rs6859      rs6859    rs6859     GRCh38.p7`

I am trying to combine the first two rows so that the combined row has the start of the first row and end of the second row like this:

`> humcon
   seqnames    start      end    TAS Proxy.start Proxy.end Assembly_NCBI
1        6 28179560 28294888 rs1635  rs78270345 rs4711167     GRCh38.p7
2        3 52833805 52847601 rs3617      rs3617 rs2071044     GRCh38.p7
3       15 91426560 91426560 rs4702      rs4702    rs4702     GRCh38.p7
4       19 45382034 45382034 rs6859      rs6859    rs6859     GRCh38.p7`

Does anyone know how I can do this please?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
library(dplyr)
humcon %>% 
  # Group by all except start and end
  group_by_at(vars(-start, -end)) %>%
  # Pick minimum of start and maximum of end
  summarise(start = min(start), end = max(end)) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: Thank you so much whalea this worked! I really appreciate your help.